# Changing awesome startup parameters

Tags: 16.04, window-manager, awesome

I'm currently trying to get awesome to work, so far it does but I have problems with my terminals not rendering properly. I've read that launching with --no-argb may help, but im not sure where exactly the parameters are defined.
I'm starting it over the login screen via the little selection thing.

Answer (score 1):

You should look in the `/usr/share/xsessions/`. For me in Ubuntu 16.04, I had  to manually add the awesome.desktop file there.

```
$ ls /usr/share/xsessions/
awesome.desktop  ubuntu.desktop
$ cat /usr/share/xsessions/awesome.desktop
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=awesome
Comment=Highly configurable framework window manager
TryExec=awesome
Exec=awesome --no-argb
Type=Application
```